# IIS returning text/html for js file, why?

Tags: javascript, iis, mime-types

When my app initially loads all is ok and in Chrome, console errors are 0. When I press the browser refresh, I receive the following error:

> Refused to execute script from
>   'http://localhost:50001/dist/vendor-es5.js' because its MIME type
>   ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is
>   enabled.

I also receive the same error for 'main-es5.js'

The error is generated from my index.cshtml file in here I have:

```
@section scripts {
    <script src="~/dist/vendor-es5.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

    <script src="~/dist/main-es5.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
}
```

changing the

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/dist/vendor-es5.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
```

still gives the same error.

my index.cshtml file resides in views/home
the dist directory resides in clientapp

if I change the reference on the script src to be ./clientapp/dist/vendor-es5.js for instance, then the app still loads correctly first time in, but then when I press the refresh, I get no console errors, but the page still doesn't refresh. Anybody have any ideas where I should go next.

Comment: seems like the webserver return incorrect MIME type for the `~/dist/vendor-es5.js`

Comment: @IAfanasov looking at the mime types in iis .js files are set to application/javascript

Comment: This is nothing to do with angular. This is a server side issue. You need to get your web server to return the correct mime type

Comment: This appears to have nothing to do with C# specifically. More likely an IIS issue.

Comment: @Liam though if it was an IIS issue, on the basis the mime type for .js file is set to 'application/javascript', then I'd expect to see this in the error as opposed to 'text/html'

Comment: Well what is the mime type in the network tab of chrome? That tells you what HTTP is being sent from IIS. If it's wrong there (which I'm pretty sure it will be) then it's a problem with IIS (or proxy or some other network device)

Comment: @Liam from the network tab in chrome for both files the type is script

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. We're going to need to see a [mcve]. My only other guess is some kind of chrome extension. Disable all extension and see if it goes away

Comment: Wait; `script`? That's not a [valid mime type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types)

Comment: @bilpor can you check IIS settings is `Static content` enabled? https://stackoverflow.com/a/42191613/943792

Answer (score 3):

First, please ensure that we have enabled the below `HTTP` feature, which makes IIS can properly process requests for static files.
[image]
It may also have something to do with the setup of your client’s build tool, for example `Webpack`.
[Refused to execute script from because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49760641/refused-to-execute-script-from-because-its-mime-type-text-html-is-not-execut)
In addition, in certain ReactJs applications, the usage of `App.use` method also might be a reason for this type of issue.

> app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/static"));

Please refer to the below links.
[loading a bundle.js file from webpack changes mime type to text/html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48157632/loading-a-bundle-js-file-from-webpack-changes-mime-type-to-text-html)
[Refused to execute script from because its MIME type (...) and strict MIME type (...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50143297/refused-to-execute-script-from-because-its-mime-type-and-strict-mime-type)
[Refused to execute script from because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49760641/refused-to-execute-script-from-because-its-mime-type-text-html-is-not-execut)
[Refused to execute script, strict MIME type checking is enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40574159/refused-to-execute-script-strict-mime-type-checking-is-enabled)